# Children's animated show where the world loses its color

Tags: story-identification

It was an animated movie or episode of a show that I remember watching as a kid, in English, likely in the early 2000's, likely on VHS, likely for an American audience.
At first I thought it was from the children's show "[The Land Before Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Land_Before_Time?wprov=sfla1)", but after looking around and watching a few episodes, I couldn't find it.
The plot is very hazy but I'll try to describe as much as I remember. I know I may not recall enough to constitute an answerable question.

The setting was the wilderness, with hills, trees, grass, and most prominently (or, so I believe) a river. The characters are a group of younglings and one or two elders/adults. Somehow, the world loses its color. Whether it was something one of the animated children did, a mistake, or some natural occurrence, I can't say. The environment, land and sky, is totally reduced to shades of gray. I think the characters themselves retained their color palette, but perhaps not. Everyone goes on a trek, a mission, to restore the colors, and they succeed. At the climax, the river I mentioned before flows with a rainbow of colors and the children, using that river of colors, begin repainting the world with paint brushes. (One or more children accidentally paint something the wrong color, i.e., leaves of a tree red, and their mistake is corrected.)

I think that's the extent of what I remember. I could've sworn this was The Land Before Time, I'm pretty shocked it's not. I hope someone out there has seen this as a kid or has shown it to their kids and recalls it. It's driving me nuts!
Thanks

Comment: This isn't the answer, but for posterity, I'm linking here to another question I asked about a cartoon in which everything loses its color:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/146930/educational-film-where-all-the-bright-colours-were-kidnapped-by-the-evil-gray-mo

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is *Dragon Tales: Staying Within The Lines* (2000).

> Ord does not want to go to sleep after he has a nightmare; Max's
> sloppy coloring becomes a problem when Dragon Land land loses its
> color and he tries to help color it back in.

Comment: How, how? How do you do it?? I got so many details wrong, and yet... Yes, this is definitely it, amazing work!

Comment: @BMF - I Searched for ***animated tv show "loses its color"*** and google served it up as the first option